# How to find an iPhone when using AirPods and Siri?

Tags: iphone, audio, siri, find-my-iphone, airpods

When I ask Siri “where’s my iPhone” it answer in my AirPods instead of making noise on the iPhone.

Any workaround there to get iPhone to speak up ?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work, the sound is set to your AirPods when you're wearing them.  When you're not wearing them, and they're charging, sound should not be routed to them.

Comment: I assume, so. =) But you not expect to have an answer on iPhone, don't you? :)

Comment: No, I don't because I'm wearing my AirPods.  I don't know why you expect the sound to come from the iPhone?  It doesn't work that way on any other device.

Comment: Ok. You have AirPods, you lost your iphone somewhere in stuff. How you can find it by using Siri?

Comment: How would you use Siri if you don't have your iPhone?  I'm confused by what you're trying to do here.  To use Siri you need a device.  Do you have another device handy that you can use to summon Siri?  I think part of the issue here is your question isn't very clear so I made some assumptions.

Comment: It's simple. I want to make some noise exactly on iPhone via AirPods, maybe via Siri. (like you can find your airpods by using iPhone)